# SharePoint 2016 Hosted App Displays Sprite Image

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app

This was all working fine awhile ago. Now the App displays a SharePoint Sprite Image overlaying the App.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

this looks to me as CSS issue, try to diagnose this problem using chrome developer tools

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/edit-styles

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint uses image maps for his sprites. If you have a display like this you have an issue with your css files.

- Check if you have any access denied or file not found issues for the css files (Use Fiddler or F12 Developer dashboard).
- Check that they have a mayor version published.
- Clear browser cache and reload the page (ctrl+F5)